# AppGyver + Parse.com + GCM

Tags: android, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging, push, appgyver

I am currently struggling with implementing Push Notifications via Parse for an  Android App with GCM .
Here is what i have and what works:
I followed the Readme Steps from the GitHub Project [Push Notifications](https://github.com/AppGyver/PushNotifications#next)
I modified the registrationHandler to register the deviceToken:

```
var req = {
  method: ‘POST’,
  url: ‘api.parse.com/1/installations’,
  headers: {
    ‘X-Parse-Application-Id’: ‘xxx’,
    ‘X-Parse-REST-API-Key’: ‘xxx’,
    ‘Content-Type’: ‘application/json’
  },
  data: {
    ‘deviceType’: ‘android’,
    ‘pushType’: ‘gcm’,
    ‘deviceToken’: deviceToken,
    ‘GCMSenderId’: senderID
  }
}
$http(req).success(function(){
  alert('Successfully registered');
}).error(function(){
  alert('Error with Registration');
});
```

I have enabled Push Notifications in the Build Configuration and am able to build and install the apk.
In the Parse Core Module i can see the registered devices. I have added the Google Project ID and API Key to Parse.
If i copy the deviceToken from the Installation Table and use it with this Ruby Script, i receive a notification immediately.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'pushmeup'

APPLICATION_API_KEY = "API_KEY_GOES_HERE"
DEVICE_REGISTRATION_ID = "REGISTRATION_ID_GOES_HERE"

GCM.host = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send'
GCM.format = :json
GCM.key = APPLICATION_API_KEY
destination = [DEVICE_REGISTRATION_ID]
data = {:message => "PhoneGap Build rocks!", :msgcnt => "1", :soundname => "beep.wav"}

puts GCM.send_notification( destination, data)
```

But I do not receive Notifications if i post them from Parse.
What am I missing?

Edit 1:
Meanwhile I had a look at LogCat and found that the messages are actually delivered to my device, but something in the processing of the message goes awry:

```
D/JsMessageQueue﹕ Enqueued JsMessage: {"from":"123456789","collapse_key":"do_not_collapse","payload":{"data":{"alert":"Testing for UUID","push_hash":"c1a7d096f1157109a590dbade5670dcd"}},"foreground":true,"coldstart":false,"timestamp":"2015-05-19T07:57Z","uuid":"f00dfc28-ef88-411c-b12d-f3eb5dba230b"}, paused: false
05-19 09:57:48.038  24772-24772/ch.hevs.asd D/JsMessageQueue﹕ Flushed 1 messages to JS side.
05-19 09:57:48.038  24772-28185/ch.hevs.asd V/GCMBaseIntentService﹕ Releasing wakelock
05-19 09:57:48.058  24772-24772/ch.hevs.asd I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(1044)] "processMessage failed: Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u", source: http://localhost/cordova.js (1044)
05-19 09:57:48.078  24772-24772/ch.hevs.asd I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(1045)] "processMessage failed: Stack: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
            at Object.parse (native)
```

Edit 2:
Ok, i debugged both incoming push notifications and the JSON i receive from both methods are different. So i think the PushPlugin from Cordova is not able to handle the JSON from Parse.com

Message from Ruby:

```
S11 PushPlugin1887095744 
{"soundname":"beep.wav",
"msgcnt":"1",
"from":"12345678",
"message":"PhoneGap rocks!",
"collapse_key":"do_not_collapse",
"payload":{},
"foreground":false,
"coldstart":false,
"timestamp":"2015-05-19T08:29Z",
"uuid":"af6605e0-1efb-4c8a-82de-d8858b2ec725"}
```

Message from Parse

```
S11 PushPlugin1887095744 
{"from":"12345678",
"collapse_key":"do_not_collapse",
"payload":{
"data":{"alert":"lets debug this PoS",
"push_hash":"1edebeb8864bc06682c10f1be1058164"}},
"foreground":false,
"coldstart":false,
"timestamp":"2015-05-19T08:25Z",
"uuid":"df575996-c039-4f5b-8120-147fb47911c9"}
```